# What is the python code to filter out lines from a text file with particular keywords?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

## My input file is a text file containing the following links

### usrls.txt

> https://www.politico.eu/article/united-kingdom-brexit-eu-david-davis-the-uks-secret-brexit-strategy-so-stealth-even-the-british-cant-see-it/
>
> https://www.reuters.com/article/us-britain-eu-scotland/scottish-independence-case-helped-by-brexit-chaos-sturgeon-idUSKBN1CD0B2
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EU_(disambiguation)

## I want to filter out links of Wikepedia from this file

### Expected Output is

### output.txt

> https://www.politico.eu/article/united-kingdom-brexit-eu-david-davis-the-uks-secret-brexit-strategy-so-stealth-even-the-british-cant-see-it/
>
> https://www.reuters.com/article/us-britain-eu-scotland/scottish-independence-case-helped-by-brexit-chaos-sturgeon-idUSKBN1CD0B2

I tried the code below but I am getting no outputs .

```
from itertools import ifilter

with open('urls.txt','rb') as f,open('fliteredlinks.txt','wb') as g:

    g.writelines( ifilter(lambda line: 'wikepedia' in line, f))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in open("urls.txt").readlines():
    if not l.startswith("https://en.wikipedia.org") : print(l)
```

This will work .